# Match Longitude and Latitude with countries in R

Tags: r, geolocation, geospatial

I would like to find the country corresponding to two different sets of coordinates. My data is set up like

| lat_1 | lon_1 | lat_2 | lon_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40.71 | 74.00 | 51.50 | 0.127 |
| 37.77 | 122.4 | 48.85 | 2.352 |

I would like the results to be stored in two new columns. So for the first row a column would say United States and another column saying England. I have tried to use a function that converts my coordinates to countries, but then I have to apply the function to one set at a time and I am not sure if they are matching up. Also with the function, it doesn't add it as an extra column.

What I have so far I listed below.

```
library(sp)
library(rworldmap)
library(dplyr)


coords2country = function(points)
{  
  countriesSP <- getMap(resolution='low')

  pointsSP = SpatialPoints(points, proj4string=CRS(proj4string(countriesSP)))  


  indices = over(pointsSP, countriesSP)


  indices$ADMIN  

}

 df <-read.csv("the_file",header=T, na.strings=c("","NA"))

 coords2country(df)
```

And when I do this I get what I described above, not what I am looking for.

Comment: If you're interested in a Shiny based solution, the shiny app included in this package will achieve what you're looking for: https://github.com/giocomai/latlon2map / here's an hosted version: https://latlon2map.europeandatajournalism.eu/ (sorry, one set at a time, but there's no reason why they wouldn't match up)

Comment: @giocomai thank you for your suggestion. Could you please show me how I would load in my two sets of coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's the full code to achieve what you're looking for, using the most recent `sf` package as a basis. For more explanations, see comments included along with the code.

```r
coords_df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~lat_1, ~lon_1, ~lat_2, ~lon_2,
   40.71,     74,   51.5,  0.127,
   37.77,  122.4,  48.85,  2.352
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(id = dplyr::row_number()) # create id column for each observation to ensure matching


# transform coordinates into a geo object (here, an sf object)
coords_sf <- coords_df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = 1:4,
                      names_to = "coord_type",
                      values_to = "coord_data") %>% 
  tidyr::separate(col = coord_type, into = c("coord_type", "set"), sep = "_") %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = coord_type, values_from = coord_data) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

coords_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0.127 ymin: 37.77 xmax: 122.4 ymax: 51.5
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>      id set        geometry
#> * <int> <chr>   <POINT [°]>
#> 1     1 1        (74 40.71)
#> 2     1 2      (0.127 51.5)
#> 3     2 1     (122.4 37.77)
#> 4     2 2     (2.352 48.85)

# get low resolution world map
world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf") %>%
  dplyr::select(name) %>% # keep only country name
  sf::st_transform(crs = 4326) %>%
  st_make_valid() # useful as of 1.0 `sf` update, see https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1649


# join columns, if you want a country only if the point is within its borders
within_sf <- sf::st_join(x = coords_sf, 
            y = world,
            join = sf::st_within)

within_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0.127 ymin: 37.77 xmax: 122.4 ymax: 51.5
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>      id set        geometry name          
#> * <int> <chr>   <POINT [°]> <chr>         
#> 1     1 1        (74 40.71) Kyrgyzstan    
#> 2     1 2      (0.127 51.5) United Kingdom
#> 3     2 1     (122.4 37.77) <NA>          
#> 4     2 2     (2.352 48.85) France

# join columns, if you want the country closest to the point
# (even if the point is not within the border of any country)
nearest_sf <- sf::st_join(x = coords_sf, 
            y = world,
            join = sf::st_nearest_feature)

nearest_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0.127 ymin: 37.77 xmax: 122.4 ymax: 51.5
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>      id set        geometry name          
#> * <int> <chr>   <POINT [°]> <chr>         
#> 1     1 1        (74 40.71) Kyrgyzstan    
#> 2     1 2      (0.127 51.5) United Kingdom
#> 3     2 1     (122.4 37.77) China         
#> 4     2 2     (2.352 48.85) France

# now you have a country for each point.
# time to go back to your original format


# again a data frame, not any more an sf object
nearest_df <- dplyr::bind_cols(nearest_sf %>%
                                 sf::st_drop_geometry(),
                               nearest_sf %>% 
                                 sf::st_coordinates() %>% 
                                 tibble::as_tibble() %>% 
                                 dplyr::rename(lon = X, lat = Y)) 

nearest_df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>      id set   name               lon   lat
#>   <int> <chr> <chr>            <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 1     Kyrgyzstan      74      40.7
#> 2     1 2     United Kingdom   0.127  51.5
#> 3     2 1     China          122.     37.8
#> 4     2 2     France           2.35   48.8

output_df <- dplyr::bind_cols(nearest_df %>% 
                   dplyr::filter(set == 1) %>% 
                   dplyr::transmute(lat_1 = lat, lon_1 = lon, name_1 = name),
                 nearest_df %>% 
                   dplyr::filter(set == 2) %>% 
                   dplyr::transmute(lat_2 = lat, lon_2 = lon, name_2 = name))


output_df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   lat_1 lon_1 name_1     lat_2 lon_2 name_2        
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         
#> 1  40.7   74  Kyrgyzstan  51.5 0.127 United Kingdom
#> 2  37.8  122. China       48.8 2.35  France
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

For reference, I'll also leave here a link to a shiny-based solution:
[https::github.com/giocomai/latlon2map](https://github.com/giocomai/latlon2map) / here's an hosted version if you want to have a quick look: [latlon2map.europeandatajournalism.eu](https://latlon2map.europeandatajournalism.eu). With this, you could load your csv, select your first set of lat lon, download the table, do it again with the other set, and merge the results in R or elsewhere.

Some of the code above is adapted from the [`ll_match()`](https://giocomai.github.io/latlon2map/reference/ll_match.html) function of the same package.

Comment: I liked the inclusion of the nearest feature. I think it would be even better to replace nearest feature by territorial waters (but I know this is not the main topic here). Also your link to the github repo is broken.

Comment: thanks, link fixed. Yes, one could probably approximate territorial waters with st_buffers, and have a residual category (or NA) for whatever is out of it, but that's all beyond the question asked.